# Web services and database concurrency

Tags: database, web-services, concurrency

I'm building a .NET client application (C#, WinForms) that uses a web service for interaction with the database. The client will be run from remote locations using a WAN or VPN, hence the idea of using a web service rather than direct database access.

The issue I'm grappling with right now is how to handle database concurrency. That is, if two people from different locations update the same data, how do I deal with it? I'm considering using timestamps on each database record and having that as part of the update where clauses, but that means that the timestamps have to move back and forth through the web service interface, which seems kind of ugly.

What is the best way to approach this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want your web service to talk directly to the database.  You probably want your service to interact with some type of business components who in turn interact with a data access layer.  Any concurrency exceptions can be passed from the DAL up to the business layer where they can be handled so that the web service never has to see the timestamps.

But if you are passing something like a data table up to the client and you want to avoid timestamps, you can do concurrency checking by comparing field by field.  The Table Adapter wizards generate this type of concurrency checking by default if you ask for optimistic concurrency checking.

Answer (score 0):

If your collisions occur infrequently enough that they can be resolved manually, a simple solution is to add an update trigger that copies a row's pre-update values to an audit table.  This way the most recent write is the "winner", but no data is ever lost to an overwrite, and an administrator can restore an earlier row state or even combine them.

This technique has its downsides, and is not a very good solution where frequent overwrites are common.

Answer (score 0):

Also, this is slightly off-topic, but using web services isn't necessarily the way to go just because the clients will be remoting into the network.  ASP.NET web services are XML-based and very verbose.  If your client application can count on being always connected, you'd be better off not using web services.

Comment: What would you propose I use instead? .NET remoting?

Comment: ADO.NET is an appropriate set of tools to use in always-connected clients.  SqlConnection and SqlCommand are the objects you would use most commonly (assuming you're using SQL Server).